# How to set SharePoint list column value to '0' on every month first Date

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation

I need to set list column with '0' value on every month 1st.

How I can achieve this one?

Answer (score 0):

Timer Job is the best suit for your requirement. But It's not possible as you have mentioned that your environment is SharePoint online.

Now you can try

[Simulate Timer Job Solution for SharePoint 2013/Online using App Model & CSOM](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shariq/2013/12/09/simulate-timer-job-solution-for-sharepoint-2013online-using-app-model-csom/)

**OR**

Write a console app using CSOM (**C#**) and run it using windows scheduler.

**OR**

[SharePoint Timer Jobs running as Windows Azure Web Jobs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/richard_dizeregas_blog/2014/04/07/sharepoint-timer-jobs-running-as-windows-azure-web-jobs/)

**OR**

You can create a workflow and run that workflow using third party app like

[Plumsail Workflow Scheduler](https://store.office.com/en-001/app.aspx?assetid=WA104313851&sourcecorrid=d519de1f-8b25-4682-a7ee-8f33777aaf2c&searchapppos=0&ui=en-US&rs=en-001&ad=US&appredirect=false)

Comment: Can we do this by using workflow ?

Comment: You can but you have to run this workflow in every month. So it's better to implement a timer job

Comment: See my last update to solve it using workflow @LavanyaPuppala